# Laravel seeding with Faker

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to seed a DB with faker. But my numbers geets seeded as 0, instead of a random number.

Seeder:

```
 'title' => $faker->sentence(3),
                'content' => $faker->paragraph(5),
                'numb' => $faker->randomDigit,
                'digi' => $faker->randomDigit,
                'tags' => join(',', $faker->words(5))
```

migration:

```
$table->integer('numb')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('digi')->unsigned();
```

All other fields gets seeded but numb and digi gets seeded as "0"

Comment: what column type are you using in your db for them?

Comment: @CrayonViolent Read the question again...

Comment: I am using int aka integer

Comment: I've tried all kinds of seeds using numbers none works. Not even rand()

Comment: I've got the feeling that the problem isn't faker but rather the actual insert. Can you show a bit more of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Problem was that I forgot to add the int fields fillable in my model

protected $fillable = array();